# Spring security database implementation exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I followed the thread in stack overflow to implemt this, but i am getting some error while i use that solution in my code.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#8': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:355)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:27)
at org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:20)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:471)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1363)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461)
... 49 more
Nov 19, 2010 10:47:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

following is my implementation

Security-context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
  <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/krams  
/auth/denied">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/auth/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/krams/auth/login" authentication-failure-url="/krams/auth/login?error=true"
                         default-target-url="/krams/main/common" />
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/krams/auth/login" logout-url="/krams/auth/logout" />
  </security:http>

  <bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.krams.tutorial.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>

  <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
      <list>
        <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"></security:authentication-provider>
  </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

I have 2 domain class person and security roles
person has user name and password and security role has authentication roles.

```
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import org.krams.tutorial.domain.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private PersonServiceImpl personService;

@Autowired
private Assembler assembler;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
try {
Person person = personService.findByName(username);
return (UserDetails) assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
} catch (NoResultException e) {
throw new UsernameNotFoundException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
}
}



@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person person) {

String username = person.getUserName();
String password = person.getPassword();
boolean enabled = person.getEnabled();
boolean accountNonExpired = person.getEnabled();
boolean credentialsNonExpired = person.getEnabled();
boolean accountNonLocked = person.getEnabled();

Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
for (SecurityRole role : person.getSecurityRoleSet()) {
authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getSecurityRole()));
 }

User user = new User(username, password, enabled,
accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
return user;
}


}
```

Guys please help me, its Priority one situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you post the nested exception??? That's where the information is.

Comment: Have edited my exception details

Comment: Are you sure you're deploying what you think you're deploying? With a quick glance (other than using both annotations and XML; don't know what, if anything, that'd do) I don't see why it's not able to convert from a `UserDetailsService` impl to a `UserDetailsService`. Is the class you show in the package `org.krams.tutorial.service`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not implement the correct `UserDetailsService`!

The `org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0`

requires a: `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`, but you 
implemented: `org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetailsService`!

For me it looks like you are mixing spring security 2.0 and 3.0.

- `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` is Spring 3.0
- `org.springframework.security.userdetails.UserDetailsService` is Spring 2.0

For one quick overview how 2.0 and 3.0 differs in there package structure have a look at this blog post: http://blog.springsource.com/2009/06/03/spring-security-300m1-released/ , there is a section description how the package names are changed.

Comment: @Junaidaj There is this gray: checkmark symbol next to the votes of the answers (Tooltip: "click to set this answer as your accepted answer"). You should use it to mark the correct answer of all questions you asked.

Comment: Ralph: I have posted another query which is related to same app which i am working on. Can you please suggest me where i went wrong there.
Question title: Spring security no hibernate session bound